# Basic Implementation of Hash Table in Python

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, hash-map

Basic impl of hash_table in python.  Supports set, get, and delete.  Uses open addressing with linear probing function.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
class Entry:
    """
        holds key, value pairs
    """
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.is_deleted = False

class Map(object):
    """
        a basic, minimal implementation of a hash map
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
            constructs a new Map
        """
        self.table = [None] * 10
        self.load_factor = .75
        self.current_size = 0

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        """
            stores the key value combo in the table
            implements open addressing collision resolution
        """
        entry = Entry(key, item)
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            index = self.__get_hash_code(key, i)

            if self.table[index] is None or self.table[index].is_deleted:
                self.table[index] = entry 
                self.current_size += 1
                if float(self.current_size) / len(self.table) >= self.load_factor:
                    self.__resize_table()
                break

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
            gets the value associated with the key
        """
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            index = self.__get_hash_code(key, i)

            if self.table[index] is not None:
                if self.table[index].key == key:
                    if self.table[index].is_deleted:
                        raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                    else:
                        return self.table[index].value

            elif self.table[index] is None:
                raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')

        raise KeyError('Hmm something has gone wrong here')

    def __get_hash_code(self, key, value):
        return (hash(key) + value) % len(self.table) 

    def __resize_table(self):
        new_table = [None] * (len(self.table) * 2)
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            new_table[i] = self.table[i]

        self.table = new_table

    def delete(self, key):
        """
            deletes a value from the hash table
        """
        for i in range(len(self.table)):
            index = self.__get_hash_code(key, i)

            if self.table[index] is not None:
                if self.table[index].key == key:
                    if self.table[index].is_deleted:
                        raise KeyError('Key is not in the map')
                    else:
                        self.table[index].is_deleted = True
                        self.current_size -= 1
                        break
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you do know that Python's `dict`s are implemented as hash tables, right (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114830/is-a-python-dictionary-an-example-of-a-hash-table)? If that is the case and this is just for fun (or educational value), we have a tag for that: [tag:reinventing-the-wheel].

Comment: Thanks for the accept! Though, next time you post code on CodeReview, you ought to wait 24-48 hours after your post for answers to come in. Accepting an answer communicates to everybody "I don't want any more answers". It's possible that someone else may have something to improve your code; you don't want to dissuade them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks generally quite good. I just have a few suggestions:

- Don't forget to define `__str__()` and `__repr__()` for each `class`
- I dislike the use of the "magic number" constants in the `__init__()` of the `Hash_Map`. They really ought to be either passed as parameters, read from a config somewhere, or clearly marked in a parameter section as pseudo-constants.
- The line `for i in range(len(self.table)):` appears multiple times. This style of loop is considered non-Pythonic. Python has the `enumerate()` built-in that returns a succession of tuples consisting of both the item and its index. I'd prefer `for (i,item) in enumerate(self.table):`
- If there's a clash, `hash(key)` will unnecessarily be called multiple times. Note that `index = self.__get_hash_code(key, i)` is called each time through the `i` loop, but the first thing it does is call `hash(key)` even though it may have already been computed. Better to compute `hash(key)` once outside the loop since it won't change.
- Multiple references to `self.table[index]`. The interpreter might be able to optimize them away, but the code will be shorter (and less error-prone) if it performs the lookup once and stores in a temp. (Or just use `enumerate()` like my previous suggestion)
- In `def __get_hash_code(self, key, value):` the third parameter is poorly named. It's not the value of the element, it's the linear probing parameter.
- There's a bug related to the interaction of `__get_hash_code()` and `__resize_table()` which can lead to \$O(n)\$ performance, defeating the purpose of using a hashtable.